# Android : Strange White Block at Top of Fragment's Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm now practicing creating a fragment with RecycleView

Everything looks fine besides one thing: there is a strange block on the top of the screen

[image]

My fragment.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CDF6CF"
    tools:context=".ui.start_trip.fragment_start_trip">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/create_a_trip_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_start_trip"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/create_a_trip_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:backgroundTint="#ED7F7F"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.884" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_start_trip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/top_start_trip"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any solution to help me get rid of this block?

Thanks, @anonymous!

Comment: your fragment seems fine. The issue may be where the view pager is. Can we see the XML for that?

Comment: You can use layout inspector tool to see what view is responsible for this "strange block".

Comment: Thanks for all the above answers!!!
I use layout inspector and find out that my problem is come from "android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" in activity_main.xml



Now I solved my question, thanks for telling the exist of layout inspector !!!

Answer (score 0):

set your recyclerView to

```
android:layout_above="@id/create_a_trip_button"
```

And i think using a Relative layout to enclose everything will be better

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion!
I will modify these settins.